# implode array without removing zero in numbers like 01

Tags: php, date, implode

I getting a date in array format, I try to implode it to string but when I do `imlode()` it removes zero form monthes and days like 01 will be equal to 1. But I need 01. How I can do this? Thanks!

Comment: Please post the code that you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could use str_pad in a foreach to add a zero before the numbers 1 till 9, then implode it.

Here is an example:

```
<?php
//filling an array for example
$days = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

foreach($days as $day){
    $newarr[] = str_pad($day, 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
}

$impld = implode('/',$newarr);
echo $impld;
?>
```

Output:

```
01/02/03/04/05/06/07/08/09/10
```